# How to change just primary color in an Angular Material pre-built theme?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-material-6

I would like to use an Angular Material pre-built theme as it helps style, e.g., buttons and tables.

However, I need to set the primary color to exactly match a brand style guide. Can just the primary color be changed on the pre-built theme?

Alternatively, would it be easier to use a custom theme and bring in the styling for buttons, etc. from a pre-built theme? If so, how would that be done?

Below is my current relevant code. The @import in styles.css gives me Anuglar Material styling, but overwrites my brand color settings.

angular.json:

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.scss", 
  "src/styles.css"
],
```

styles.css:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

styles.scss:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

$my-purple: (
  50: #e9e3ed,
  100: #c8b9d3,
  200: #a38bb5,
  300: #7e5c97,
  400: #623981,
  500: #46166b,
  600: #3f1363,
  700: #371058,
  800: #2f0c4e,
  900: #20063c,
  A100: #ad73ff,
  A200: #8f40ff,
  A400: #720dff,
  A700: #6500f2,
  contrast: (
    50: $black-87-opacity,
    100: $black-87-opacity,
    200: $black-87-opacity,
    300: $black-87-opacity,
    400: white,
    500: white,
    600: $white-87-opacity,
    700: $white-87-opacity,
    800: $white-87-opacity,
    900: $white-87-opacity,
    A100: $black-87-opacity,
    A200: $black-87-opacity,
    A400: white,
    A700: $white-87-opacity,
  )
);

$primary: mat-palette($my-purple);
$accent:  mat-palette($my-purple, A200, A100, A400);
$warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);
$theme:   mat-light-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);

@include angular-material-theme($theme);
```

Comment: Because you are defining your own custom theme, you don't need to import the predefined theme. So you can remove the import from styles.css or remove the whole file and just use styles.scss. Normally it's one or the other, but not both.

Comment: @G.Tranter yes, but then is there any way to import other pre-built styles, like for buttons, etc.?

Comment: That can all go in styles.scss. Think of it as the SASS version of your global style sheet. You can have ordinary global CSS as well as SASS and use mixins etc.